# При вызове методов класса выполняется одно и то же

Tags: python, ооп

**Всем привет! Вопрос на Stackoverflow пишу впервые.** Написал парсер статей разных категорий одним классом, где методы это категории. Дальше при вызове методов  класса передаю классу аргумент ссылку на статьи данной категории, где беру первую попавшуюся статью. Но когда вызываю метод класса дважды с другой ссылкой, выводиться то же самое что и в первом случае. Не понимаю в чем проблема. Заранее спасибо всем откликнувшимся!

вот код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


class Parser:
    info = []

    def __init__(self, uri):
        self.uri = uri
        r = requests.get(self.uri)
        html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

        for article in html.select('article'):
            self.info.append({
                'title': article.find('a', class_='post__title_link').text.strip(),
                'categories': [category.text for category in article.find_all('a', class_='inline-list__item-link')],
                'author': article.find('span', class_='user-info__nickname').text.strip(),
                'time': article.find('span', class_='post__time').text.strip(),
                'content': article.find('div', class_='post__text').text.strip(),
            })


    def python(self):
        print(self.info[0])
        print()

    def cpp(self):
        print()
        print(self.info[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Parser('https://habr.com/ru/hub/python/').python()
    Parser('https://habr.com/ru/hub/cpp/').cpp()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/q/68645

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


class Parser:
    def __init__(self, uri):
        self.info = []
        self.uri = uri
        r = requests.get(self.uri)
        html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

        for article in html.select('article'):
            self.info.append({
                'title': article.find('a', class_='post__title_link').text.strip(),
                'categories': [category.text for category in article.find_all('a', class_='inline-list__item-link')],
                'author': article.find('span', class_='user-info__nickname').text.strip(),
                'time': article.find('span', class_='post__time').text.strip(),
                'content': article.find('div', class_='post__text').text.strip(),
            })


    def python(self):
        print(self.info[0])
        print()

    def cpp(self):
        print()
        print(self.info[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Parser('https://habr.com/ru/hub/python/').python()
    Parser('https://habr.com/ru/hub/cpp/').cpp()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, много замучился, а решение оказалось таким простым!